# why my register form is working and my login form does not

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, model-view-controller

i am using the default microsoft template for registration and login pages. I merged both pages in one view. When i am registering a new user the website is working and the index page is showing up but when i am trying to login it says that i am trying to pass a loginViewModel instead of ViewModel. I cant understand why the error is showing up but i cant understand why is working for registration and not for login since i am using the same approach for both pages. Can anyone help me fix this?

Here is my code:

Login view:

```
    @using my_app.Models
    @model my_app.Models.ViewModel

    <div class="split right">
        <div class="hold-transition login-page img-bg-mine" background="~/imgs/dog3.jpg">
            <div class="centeredright">
                <div class="login-box">

                    <div class="login-logo">
                        <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Pet</b>Care</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.login-logo -->
                    <div class="login-box-body">
                        <p class="login-box-msg">Login to start your session</p>

                        @Html.Partial("_Login")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="split left">
            <div class="hold-transition login-page img-bg-mine" background="~/imgs/dog3.jpg">
                <div class="centeredleft">
                    <div class="login-box">

                        <div class="login-logo">
                            <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Pet</b>Care</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.login-logo -->
                        <div class="login-box-body">
                            <p class="login-box-msg">Register to start your session</p>

                            @Html.Partial("_Register")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
// POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            var model1 = new ViewModel();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout   
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true   
            ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {

                //After he signs in check his role and you will redirect him to the correct page
                //User.IsInRole use this(returns true or false)
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                   // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

        }

 // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                   // var role = dbContext.AspNetRoles.Find(Convert.ToInt32(model.Role));

                    //var role = new IdentityRole(model.Role.Name);
                    //I added this line to store the user and its roles in AspNetUserRoles table:
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role);
                    //result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role);
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                    //Assign Role to user Here      
                   // await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = dbContext.AspNetRoles.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id, Text = c.Name });
                ViewBag.RoleList = items;
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            LoginViewModel mod = new LoginViewModel();
            return View("Login");
        }
```

Model:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public LoginViewModel LoginModel { get; set; }
        public RegisterViewModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are returning object `model` which is of type `LoginViewModel` which comes from method parameters. You define that your view expects `ViewModel`, hence the error. You instanciate `var model1 = new ViewModel();` but never make use of it. You ant to return that instead.

`if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                **return View(model);**
            }`

`ase SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    **return View(model);**
                   // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

Comment: this isnt working because in _login partial i am using LoginViewModel and when i am trying to pass the model1 i have the error "'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'my_app.Models.ViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'my_app.Models.LoginViewModel'."